# Typing a complex recursive function to use within itself without circular reference errors

Tags: typescript, circular-dependency, typescript-generics, circular-reference, redux-toolkit

Let's say I have a function, that's built using a really complex builder function:

```js
const myFunction = createComplexFunction<X,Y,Z>(val1, (val2,val3)=>{
// My function code here
});
```

if it helps, this builder function is `createAsyncThunk` from redux-toolkit, but it's omitted for simplicity.

Now, I want this function to be able to pass its own reference down to another function (just in case its used recursively), so I have `recursiveHelper` inside this builder's 2nd parameter where I pass the reference of `myFunction` to

```js
const myFunction = createComplexFunction<X,Y,Z>(val1, (val2,val3)=>{

    recursiveHelper(myFunction, 'Extra Data')

});
```

Now, I really need to type the first parameter of `recursiveHelper` to whatever `myFunction` is, however this doesn't seem too easy.

I first tried

```js
export type MyFunctionType=typeof myFunction;
```

but if I ever try use it within `myFunction` I get a circular typing reference warning, which makes sense.
Constructing this type myself is near impossible, its incredibly complex. I really need a way to extract it somehow.

I then tried

```js
export type MyFunctionType=typeof createComplexFunction;
```

this works too, but this `createComplexFunction` has a lot of generics I need to set manually for it to be useful. In fact, I don't even know if it'll work in the end because using this type led to error `TS7022` which is another variant of a circular warning.

Doing this if `TS7022` wasn't an issue might help:

```js
export type MyFunctionType=typeof createComplexFunction<T,U,V>
```

But its not possible.

Any idea how to get the type of my recursive function, `myFunction` built with `createComplexFunction`, generics and all so I can correctly type `recursiveHelper`'s first parameter? Or is there some other approach I can take entirely?

...

`TS7022` for reference:

```
... implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer
```

Comment: where is the return type of the `createComplexFunction` function defined?

Comment: @TomerAmir You can find the exact typing here: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/master/etc/redux-toolkit.api.md, can't get a link to a line, so try searching `createAsyncThunk` on that page. It looks like its `AsyncThunk<Returned, ThunkArg, ThunkApiConfig>`.

Comment: So can't you just use this type? :)

Comment: ah yes! I'm an idiot. Viewing the type in my IDE, I was too intimidated to even try haha. While I verify it works, you are welcome to get an answer ready for some free points :)

Comment: @TomerAmir on second rundown, it doesn't seem that easy...I can't find it in the Github Repo, but in the declaration file, the return type is: ```IsAny<ThunkArg, (arg: ThunkArg) => AsyncThunkAction<Returned, ThunkArg, ThunkApiConfig>, unknown extends...``` plus a lot more gibberish. They have a really nice type `AsyncThunk` I mentioned earlier that they use internally, which they don't expose it to us :( I hope there's a solution that doesn't involve manually typing this out haha

Comment: Are you sure? looking in the `typings.d.ts` file I can see `export declare type AsyncThunk<...` and it works for me to import it

Comment: @TomerAmir after updating my dependencies, its there in the latest version. Thanks for checking :)